# Typescript draggable slider

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript

I need help to create a draggable slider in TS. I am able to get the client and scroll positions but I'm unable to mutate the ref scrollLeft position. It doesn't return or throw an error, it just doesn't mutate that ref's scrollLeft property.

I've tried logging the ref property that returns the div ref but the scrollLeft position is always 0

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from "react";
import Nav from "./Nav";

const Services: React.FC = () => {
    const ref = useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);
    const [state, setState] = useState({
        isDown: false,
        clientX: 0,
        scrollX: 0,
    });
    const onMouseDown = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement>): void => {
        e.persist();
        setState({
            ...state, isDown: true,
            clientX: e.clientX,
        });
    };

    const onMouseUp = () => {
        setState({ ...state, isDown: false });
    };
    const onMouseLeave = () => {
        setState({ ...state, isDown: false });
    };

    const onMouseMove = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement>): void => {
        e.persist();
        if (!state.isDown) { return; }
        const { clientX, scrollX } = state;
        if (ref.current) {
            // console.log(ref.current.scrollLeft);
            ref.current.scrollLeft = scrollX + e.clientX - clientX;
            console.log(ref.current.scrollLeft, scrollX + e.clientX - clientX);
            // state.scrollX = scrollX + e.clientX - clientX;
            // state.clientX = e.clientX;
     }
    };
    return (
        <main>
            <Nav/>
            <div id="content">
                <div className="draggable-slider" ref={ref}
                    onMouseDown={onMouseDown}
                    onMouseUp={onMouseUp}
                    onMouseLeave={onMouseLeave}
                    onMouseMove={onMouseMove}>
                   <div className="slide">
                       <h3>.01</h3>
                       <h3>Basic</h3>
                       <div className="slide-image">1</div>
                   </div>
                   <div className="slide">
                        <h3>.02</h3>
                        <h3>Basic</h3>
                       <div className="slide-image">2</div>
                   </div>
                   <div className="slide">
                        <h3>.03</h3>
                        <h3>Basic</h3>
                       <div className="slide-image">3</div>
                   </div>
                   <div className="slide">
                        <h3>.04</h3>
                        <h3>Basic</h3>
                       <div className="slide-image">4</div>
                   </div>
               </div>
            </div>
        </main>
    );
};

export default Services;
```

The CSS

````
.draggable-slider {
    position: relative;
    display: grid;
    padding: 1rem;
    width: 100%;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 400px);
    grid-column-gap: 3em;
    top: 35vh;
    user-select: none;
    background-color: red;

    .slide {
      padding: 10px;
      line-height: 1;
    //   cursor: grab;

    // &.is-grabbing{
    //   cursor: grabbing;
    //    }

    ```

I want to be able to create the draggable slide by mutating the div scrollLeft position
````

Comment: hmm... in `scrollX + e.clientX - clientX`.. are `scrollX` and `clientX` different values? rather, is `const { clientX, scrollX } = state` working as you expect here?

Comment: actually.. go ahead and update your question with your relevant css.. as it isn't clear that you are using `scrollLeft` correctly and\or have the correct expectations of it (i.e. your `content` container should have a horizontal scrollbar; `overflow` should allow for scrollbar)

Comment: @BrettCaswell, those values are working as expected. ref.current.scrollLeft position is not just being reassigned despite setting it to those values.

Comment: your usage of `ref` seems correct.. I tested similar code.. perhaps the name of the variable should be something other then `ref`.

Comment: I tried that also, didn't seem to work. Something like divRef

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is flawed here: 
`ref.current.scrollLeft = scrollX + e.clientX - clientX;`. If you log the value of that operation, you'll see that it is a *negative number*.

According to the MDN docs on[`Element.scrollLeft`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollLeft):

> If specified as a value less than 0 (greater than 0 for right-to-left elements), scrollLeft is set to 0.

This explains why you see it always at 0. You can see this here in a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-wilson-je2ih).

Hope that gets you unstuck! Good luck!